# dragover event is no not firing in firefox

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm working to simulate files and directories structure ,using drag and drop,
my code is working fine in IE, Chrome but not working in Firefox ,
while i'm searching i found this fiddle .

```
>  http://jsfiddle.net/G9mJw/20/
```

same problem works on IE,Chrome but not Firefox !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/G9mJw/140/

```
var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
var draggable = document.getElementById('draggable');

draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, false);
dropzone.ondragover = function(e){e.preventDefault();  }
dropzone.ondrop = function(e){ onDragOver(e); } 

function onDragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', null); //cannot be empty string
}
function onDragOver(event) {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```